# setting legend only for one of the marginal plots in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am creating a JointGrid plot using seaborn.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mydataset=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50,2),columns=['a','b'])
g = sns.JointGrid(x=mydataset['a'], y=mydataset['b'])
g=g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot,color='black',kde=True,hist=False,rug=True,bins=20,label='X')
g=g.plot_joint(plt.scatter,label='X')        


legend_properties = {'weight':'bold','size':8}
legendMain=g.ax_joint.legend(prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')


legendSide=g.ax_marg_x.legend(prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')
```

I get this:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the legend within the vertical marginal plot (the one on the right side) but keep the one for the horizontal margin.
how to achieve that?

---

EDIT: The solution from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest works fine for one plot. However, if I repeat it in a for loops something unexpected happens.
I still get a legend in the upper plot and that is unexpected.
How to get rid of it?

The following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mydataset=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50,2),columns=['a','b'])
g = sns.JointGrid(x=mydataset['a'], y=mydataset['b'])
LABEL_LIST=['x','Y','Z']
for n in range(0,3):

    g=g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot,color='black',kde=True,hist=False,rug=True,bins=20,label=LABEL_LIST[n])
    g=g.plot_joint(plt.scatter,label=LABEL_LIST[n])        


    legend_properties = {'weight':'bold','size':8}
    legendMain=g.ax_joint.legend(prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')


    legendSide=g.ax_marg_y.legend(labels=[LABEL_LIST[n]],prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')
```

gives:

[image]

which is almost perfect, byt I need to get rid of the last legend entry in the plo on the right.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: That might be expected or strange, depending on what is inside the marginals. So please create a [mcve] of the issue and clearly state what you would expect the legend to show and why.

Comment: Yes I am doing that just now

Comment: I hope this meet requirements now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may decide not to give any label to the marginals, but instead add the label when creating the legend inside the top marginal axes.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydataset=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50,2),columns=['a','b'])
g = sns.JointGrid(x=mydataset['a'], y=mydataset['b'])
g=g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot,color='black',
                   kde=True,hist=False,rug=True,bins=20)
g=g.plot_joint(plt.scatter,label='X')        


legend_properties = {'weight':'bold','size':8}
legendMain=g.ax_joint.legend(prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')


legendSide=g.ax_marg_x.legend(labels=["x"], 
                              prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

The solution is the same for a plot in a loop.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydataset=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50,2),columns=['a','b'])
g = sns.JointGrid(x=mydataset['a'], y=mydataset['b'])
LABEL_LIST=['x','Y','Z']
for n in range(0,3):
    g=g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot,color='black',kde=True,hist=False,rug=True,bins=20)
    g=g.plot_joint(plt.scatter,label=LABEL_LIST[n])        

legend_properties = {'weight':'bold','size':8}
legendMain=g.ax_joint.legend(prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')
legendSide=g.ax_marg_x.legend(labels=LABEL_LIST,prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You are answer is correct, and I will accept it...but

Comment: I am doing this operation in a loop, where I add 3 of these plots on 1 single axis. Would this still work?

Comment: sorry, i have edited the question...later on I would accept your answer anyway but if you can give it an extra look...

Comment: Now I'm lost. You wanted to get rid of the legend in the right axes. Now you want to get rid of the one on top?

Comment: As said you should not give any label to the marginals, but only use the legend you create manually. This must be outside the loop, else you end up with the next legend replacing the previous.